# HTML Form - Both Select Options not showing

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to code a select/option box in a form in HTML, but when I viewed it, only one of the options (the one which was recently scrolled over) shows.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<form name="quizform">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label>1) Do you smoke?</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <select name="smokes?">
                        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                        <option value="no">No</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

CSS:
I have not written any CSS code for the form.

Images of the problem:

[image]
[image]

BTW: I am using `bootstrap.css`

Comment: I assume something is changing the font color of your select options.  Try inspecting it to narrow down where the style is being applied.

Comment: Maybe show us your CSS? Might be mistake with default CSS.

Comment: Do you have other CSS than just the default bootstrap files? Because what you've posted wouldn't do that.

Comment: can you please share a demo link? or jsfiddle link?

Comment: Are you really using bootstrap css? because in your images the style of the select input doesn't look like a bootstrap input

Answer (score 3):

It is aparent that your font is white and your background is also white, so only when you hover or scroll or select an item, actions which probably change the background color to blue, does the text show.  You need to change either your background or your foreground color

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Identified the problem perfectly.

Comment: And don't add CSS to your html.  Go to your bootstrap.css that you said you are using, find what is setting the background and foreground, and change as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The font color for your dropdown options is white as well as it's background, so only when you hover over it which changes the background to blue do you see the text. Add this CSS code below on the select to change the color of the text options.

//CSS

```
select{
   color: black;
   background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Identified the problem perfectly. Also, thanks for the CSS.

Comment: @user2733385 yea no problem! let me know if you need help with anything else.